# Gurobi addConstr with MVar: Index 0 out of range for attribute 'X'

Tags: python, gurobi

I am very new to Gurobi, and currently working on a feasibility optimization problem, where as part of my variables, I have an MVar grid (matrix) `grid_values`, and another one `b1` defined as such:

```
grid_values = model.addMVar( (n, n), lb=1, ub=9, vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name="grid_values")
b1 = model.addMVar((n, n), vtype=GRB.BINARY, name='b1')
```

Now, I was trying to add some constraints I have where each constraint involves a row of `grid_values` and a row of `b1`:

```
model.addConstrs(((grid_values[i, :] - j ).getValue() @ b1[i, :] == 0 
                  for i in range(n)
                  for j in range(n)), name='row_constr')
```

Where `j` is the vector of all 1's, then all 2's, ... all n's. However, when I run the above code I get:

> GurobiError: Index 0 out of range for attribute 'X'.

Where did I go wrong? Any help is appreciated.

I also tried using `np.full((n,), j)` instead of `j` for the vector, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that the `getValue()` method computes the value of a MLinExpr object (linear matrix expression) in the current solution, i.e. after you solved your optimization problem.

Then, as far as I know, for now there's no way to do a "pointwise" multiplication like a dot product with Mvar objects. So you could either try to write the constraint in form of a simple matrix-vector product or use the known algebraic modeling approach instead of the matrix api:

```
from gurobipy import Model, GRB, quicksum

model = Model()
grid_values = model.addVars(n, n, lb=1, ub=9, vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name="grid_values")
b1          = model.addVars(n, n, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="b1")

model.addConstrs((quicksum((grid_values[i,j]-j)*b1[i,j] for j in range(n)) == 0 for i in range(n)), name="row_constr")
```